# ip route show src filed

Tags: linux, routing, iproute2

I read the man page of `ip` and still do not understand what `src` is and I could not find much documentation.

Please, if you can explain it thoroughly or point to some link it a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   src ADDRESS
          the source address to prefer when sending to the destinations covered by the route prefix.
```

Nowadays, especially with IPv6, it is often possible to have multiple IP addresses on a single interface. That means that a route such as

```
ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0
```

does not uniquely determine the source IP of the packages anymore (as it had been the case if `eth0` only had one IP address). Therefore, it is possible to specify a specific source address using the `src` statement. The Linux kernel usually uses the newest address.

This is especially useful if you want to use IPv6 with privacy extensions. The kernel would then normally use the latest temporary address. However, you can make it use a specific permanent address when accessing a particular (for example, local) network using the `src` statement.